# I want to get the list of opened application in taskbar using Java

Tags: java

I am making an application in Java, I want to get a list of all the opened application in the taskbar. I tried this code,

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
        System.getenv("windir") + "\\system32\\" +
        "tasklist.exe /v /FI \"STATUS eq RUNNING\"");
```

but I want only running application, not all the processes.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use the `tasklist` command. Meaning: instead of running `windir`, you simply execute that other command and process its output.

Outlined [here](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/93197/how-to-get-the-running-applications-in-windows-task-manager-using-java) for an example that uses Java to call it; and [there](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491010.aspx) for documentation about the tool itself.